# getting a 404 error AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404'

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, serverside-javascript

im trying to run my frontend and server side app but im getting this error when i try to update my dog profile

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/dog-profile/dogprofile 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:272
xhr @ xhr.js:63
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:61
_request @ Axios.js:179
request @ Axios.js:49
httpMethod @ Axios.js:218
wrap @ bind.js:9
onSubmit @ dogprofile.js:46
eval @ index.esm.mjs:2214
await in eval (async)
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
eval @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26135
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
Show 23 more frames
Show less
dogprofile.js:57 Error updating dog profile: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Request failed with status code 404"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}response: {data: {…}, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:125:66)\n    at Axios.request (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:54:41)\n    at async onSubmit (webpack-internal:///./pages/dogprofile.js:55:30)\n    at async eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.esm.mjs:2214:13)"[[Prototype]]: Error
```

ive been stuck on this for hours now and im so lost on what to do.
This is what i have on my frontend dogprofile.js

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import api from '../services/api';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const DogProfile = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm();
  const [dogProfile, setDogProfile] = useState({
    name: '',
    breed: '',
    age: '',
    weight: '',
    aggressionStatus: '',
    lastVisitDate: ''
  });
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userLoggedIn')));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDogProfile = async () => {
      try {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
        const response = await api.get('/dog-profile/dogprofile', {
          headers: {
            'x-auth-token': token
          }
        });
        setDogProfile(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching dog profile:', error);
      }
    };

    if (user) {
      fetchDogProfile();
    }
  }, [user]);

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
      const response = await api.put('/dog-profile/dogprofile', data, {
        headers: {
          'x-auth-token': token
        }
      });
      console.log(response);
      toast.success('Dog profile updated successfully', {
        autoClose: 1000,
        position: "bottom-center"
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating dog profile:', error);
      toast.error('Failed to update dog profile');
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className='my-3'>Dog Profile</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Form.Group controlId="name">
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control defaultValue={dogProfile.name} {...register('name')} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="breed">
          <Form.Label>Breed</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control defaultValue={dogProfile.breed} {...register('breed')} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="age">
          <Form.Label>Age</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control defaultValue={dogProfile.age} {...register('age')} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="weight">
          <Form.Label>Weight</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control defaultValue={dogProfile.weight} {...register('weight')} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="aggressionStatus">
          <Form.Label>Aggression Status</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control defaultValue={dogProfile.aggressionStatus} {...register('aggressionStatus')} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="lastVisitDate">
          <Form.Label>Last Visit Date</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="date" defaultValue={dogProfile.lastVisitDate} {...register('lastVisitDate')} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Save Changes
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

export default DogProfile;
```

and these are my serverside files

dogProfileController.js

```
const DogProfile = require("../models/dogProfile");

const getDogProfile = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const dogProfile = await DogProfile.findOne({ owner: req.user.userId });
    if (!dogProfile) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Dog profile not found" });
    }
    res.json(dogProfile);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching dog profile:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
};

const updateDogProfile = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Logic for updating dog profile based on the user's ID from req.user
    const updatedDogProfile = await DogProfile.findOneAndUpdate(
      { owner: req.user.userId }, // Filter by owner ID
      req.body, // Update with request body
      { new: true } // Return the updated document
    );
    if (!updatedDogProfile) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Dog profile not found" });
    }
    console.log("Updated Dog Profile:", updatedDogProfile);
    res.json(updatedDogProfile);
    console.log("Dog profile updated successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating dog profile:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
};

module.exports = {
  getDogProfile,
  updateDogProfile,
};
```

models/dogProfile.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dogProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  owner: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Customer", required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  breed: { type: String, required: true },
  age: { type: Number, required: true },
  weight: { type: Number, required: true },
  aggressionStatus: { type: String, required: true },
  lastVisitDate: { type: Date, required: true },
});

const DogProfile = mongoose.model("DogProfile", dogProfileSchema);

module.exports = DogProfile;
```

routes/dogProfileRoutes.js

```
// routes/dogProfileRoutes.js

const express = require("express");
const Dog = require("../models/dogProfile");
const dogProfileController = require("../controllers/dogProfileController");
const authMiddleware = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");
const router = express.Router();

router.use(authMiddleware);

router.get("/dogprofile", dogProfileController.getDogProfile);
router.put("/dogprofile", dogProfileController.updateDogProfile);

module.exports = router;
```

routes.js
// routes/routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const authRoutes = require('./authRoutes');
const appointmentRoutes = require('./appointmentRoutes');
const customerRoutes = require('./customerRoutes');
const aboutRoute = require('./aboutRoute'); // Import the aboutRoute module
const servicesRoute = require('./servicesRoute'); // Import the servicesRoute module
const contactsRoute = require('./contactsRoute'); // Import the contactsRoute module
const homeRoute = require('./homeRoute'); // Import the homeRoute module
const dogProfileRoutes = require('./dogProfileRoutes'); // Import the dogProfileRoutes module

const router = express.Router();

// Delegate specific functionalities to separate route files
router.use('/auth', authRoutes);
router.use('/appointments', appointmentRoutes);
router.use('/customers', customerRoutes);
router.use('/dog-profile', dogProfileRoutes); 
// Include the about route
router.use('/about', aboutRoute);
router.use('/services', servicesRoute); // Include the services route
// Include the contacts route
router.use('/contacts', contactsRoute);
// Include the home route
router.use('/', homeRoute);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Looks like your server configuration is correct, so it must mean that you are failing due to the dog not being found in the db from
`if (!updatedDogProfile) { return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Dog profile not found" }); }`
maybe the dog doesnt belong to `req.user.userId` or maybe the request.body is not in the correct format and it is not finding by id

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help but maybe there's a problem in matching the frontend routing in you 'response'.

```
 const response = await api.get('/dog-profile/dogprofile', {
      headers: {
        'x-auth-token': token
      }
```

try removing /dog-profile

Comment: i tried that but it still gave me the same error